# Woocommerce Single Product Tabs Got Duplicate

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have just change the order of these lines of code for some changing in single product template.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
```

After toggling the numeric digit at the first two lines i am getting duplicate tabs. If i reorder them it will revert back to the default position. Kindly assist me what can i do. Thanks

Comment: It's likely because you haven't removed the default hooks, which results in the *same callback being hooked twice to the same action*.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, Could please assist me which file i need to edit

Comment: You can add the code in the theme functions file (i.e. `functions.php`) and have a look at this [example](https://pastebin.com/AppPTC0V).

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks a lot for help but that not work me, i dont know why but the good thing is i have fixed it through css to display:none the first child and works great.

Comment: Ok then. But you should post an answer - and accept it - so that people know the question has an accepted solution. :) All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a quick solution for this problem. Unable to remove action as Sally mentioned above with example.For me the display:none; is enough, i have remove the child div of summary class. See the code below:

```
.summary.entry-summary div:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
```

For me its 5th child maybe it will help others.